# Наиболее значительный?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить «наиболее значительный»?
Уместно ли здесь слово *наиболее*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Контекст нужен.

Грамматически - да, можно, прилагательное качественное и формально может иметь сравнительную степень (см. @ЕкатеринаКаштанова). Но если употреблено не к месту, то сразу возникает стилистическая ошибка.

Видимо, такое может быть, если есть критерий для численной оценки "значительности". "Более значительный вклад в банке" - это нонсенс, поскольку обычно таковым считается вклад выше определенного значения, а насколько выше - совершенно не важно. Значит и сравнивать значительность нельзя.

А вот "более значительный вклад" в науку в принципе может существовать, есть автор уверен, что знает, *как померить* вклады (скажем, в Общую Теорию Всего академика Первачева и профессора Вторушникова) *чиcлом*. А потом эти числа сравнить. Хотя и это спорно, не по числу же дырок на лацкане сравнивать?!

> Возник спор именно о правомерности (литературности) словосочетания
>   "наиболее значительный"

Если вопрос стоит именно так, то в 99% случаев это будет стилистической небрежностью, хотя грамматически допустимо.

Comment: Благодарю Вас. Вот часть предложения (всё оно длинное):
"Среди коровых землетрясений наиболее значительным событием 2010 г. стало ощутимое  землетрясение, которое произошло..."
Прошу меня простить, немного спутала с другим подобным предложением. Здесь речь идёт, конечно же, о событии, а не вкладе. Но это проблему не решает.
Есть ещё предложение, которое коробит меня своим звучанием: "Наиболее существенный вклад в это число внесло сильное землетрясение..." (Где "число" - это значение (цифра) выделившейся энергии, приведено в предыдущем предложении).

Comment: Наталья, во-первых, если появились новые вопросы или вадные изменения, всегда или дополняйте вопрос, или открывайте новую тему (по ситуации), но в комментариях тесно для таких вещей. Во-вторых, Ваши уточнения не просто существенны - они в корне меняют ситуацию. Оба ваших примера (значительное событие и существенный вклад) - вполне сносно выглядят с "наибольшим" - на первый взгляд по крайней мере. Но это надо заново смотреть и осмысливать. Вот "вклад в число" - это точно отдельная тема. Открывайте.

Comment: Нет необходимости открывать новую тему про "вклад в число", поскольку и так понятно, что это неверно. Привела его для того, чтобы оправдать свою невнимательность. В моей голове крутятся два эти предложения несколько дней, поэтому всё перемешалось, и я задала неточную тему для обсуждения, за что прошу меня извинить. Спасибо за корректную правку темы. Тем не менее, у меня устойчивое ощущение того, что слова "наиболее" и "значительный" не сочетаются друг с другом для использования в публикациях (по аналогии с "наиболее хороший").  И неважно, какое за ними следует существительное.

Comment: До создания темы на этом сайте я приставала со своим вопросом к знакомым филологам, и ответы также весьма разнились. Если можно привести примеры употребления данных слов в корректно построенном предложении, буду всем очень признательна.

Comment: *от прилагательного "значительный" сравнительная форма может быть образована (если я правильно поняла) только синтетическим способом*  - так не бывает. Аналитическая форма более мощная, она по логике всегда есть, если есть синтетическая.  Сейчас посмотрю, что там за правила.

Comment: Ну как я и думал, Вы неверно поняли. Не знаю источник, поэтому не буду разбираться уж очень глубоко, но если коротко, там есть правила по которым возможно образование синтетической формы: когда и как она образуется, причем это только грамматические правила, ограничения на семантику там даже не упоминаются. ***И тем более там не утверждается, что в рассматриваемых случаях - или в каких-то еще - невозможно образование аналитической формы***. Подразумевается, что ***аналитическая форма существует всегда***. Вот чем плохи такие сайты: их непросвещенному без толмача читать невозможно.    ))))

Comment: Таким образом, делаю вывод, что на вкус и цвет товарищей нет. Если люди так пишут, значит, упрекнуть их не в чем. Дело вкуса автора. Мне это не нравится, но статья не моя, поэтому нет рычагов, на которые можно нажать, чтобы написать по-другому ))
Верно?

Comment: Нет, у вас хватает ошибок и в посылках и в логике. Но всего перечислять в комментариях не буду. Еще раз говорю, это тема для отдельного вопроса, о взаимоотношениях нормы и практики. Здесь нет правил, что миллион лемингов не может ошибаться. . По сути же добавить мне нечего. Последние представленные варианты  в части образования сравнительных и превосходных степеней не содержат ни грамматических, ни стилистических ошибок. А что там по контексту получается - это надо смотреть отдельно

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

*Значительный* - качественное прилагательное. Следовательно, признак может проявляться в большей или меньшей степени. *Наиболее значительный* - форма превосходной степени прилагательного *значительный*. Всё правильно.

Comment: Благодарю, Екатерина. Но. К примеру, "хороший" - тоже качественное прилагательное, но мы же не говорим "наиболее хороший".

Comment: "Хороший" - не тот пример. Семантика образованию сравнительной степени не препятствует.. Просто для "более хороший" есть другая форма, супплетивная.  А вот "более деревянный" и, скажем,  "более международный" вызывают законные вопросы.

Answer (score 0):

Уместно, если Вы хотите подчеркнуть неоценимую его роль для развития чего-либо. А вот "наиболее значительнейший" сказать нельзя.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Так можно сказать в случае, когда среди "внесших значительный вклад" нужно выделить кого-то одного, причём "наибольший вклад" (количество полезного труда) в этом конкретном случае не совпадает с "наиболее значительным" (мало этим занимался, зато, например, высказал гипотезу, без которой у других "внесших" ничего не вышло бы). В обычной же ситуации проще сказать "наибольший вклад".

Comment: Большое спасибо. Но звучит как-то коряво. Очень хочется заменить другим выражением.

Comment: Мне это тоже кажется излишне официальным. Можно сказать и "самый значительный", если по упомянутым мной причинам не очень подходит "наибольший".

Comment: Большое спасибо. Чем заменить - это уже другой вопрос. Возник спор именно о правомерности (литературности) словосочетания "наиболее значительный".

Comment: Вы не путайте. Наиболее значительный - это совсем не то, что наибольший. А если бы это и было синонимично, то зачем использовать _более неуклюжий_] вариант?